# Generate specific template in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there any way to generate specific template in beforeCreate hook according a statement?
I have three roles in my program and I want to generate a specific template foreach roles.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could share some code, but what is used in most situations like this could be something as this example :

in your data set something like this:

```
role: undefined
```

and set this role in something like `Created` or `Mounted`

In your template you can use several `v-if` statements

```
// template 1
.div(v-if='role === "staff"')
  content here

// template 2
.div(v-if='role === "visitor"')
  content here

// template 3
.div(v-if='role === "ceo"')
  content here
```